# value of cell in the specified range on rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

i would like to get the temperature value for the corresponding temperature timestamp, from the specified range of cells.
e.g would like to get temperature value of corresponding temperature_time_stamp from 27-04-2020 05:32 to 27-04-2020 05:33.
im using pandas for reading the file in python.

```
Temperature_TimeStamp   Temperature
27-04-2020 05:31        91.75
27-04-2020 05:31        91.73
27-04-2020 05:32        91.75
27-04-2020 05:32        91.73
27-04-2020 05:32        91.77
27-04-2020 05:33        91.73
27-04-2020 05:33        91.69
27-04-2020 05:34        91.69
27-04-2020 05:34        91.69
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for one timestamp, and want to get all the corresponding temperatures:

```
timestamp = '27-04-2020 05:31'
mask = df.Temperature_TimeStamp.eq(timestamp)
df.loc[mask, 'Temperature']
```

If you want to sample a range of time

```
# Make sure df['Temperature_TimeStamp'] is in datetime format
df['Temperature_TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Temperature_TimeStamp'])

start_time = pd.to_datetime('27-04-2020 05:30')
end_time = pd.to_datetime('27-04-2020 05:32')

mask = (df['Temperature_TimeStamp'] > start_time) & (df['Temperature_TimeStamp'] <= end_time)
df.loc[mask, 'Temperature']
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert valeus of column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `dayfirst=True` parameter and then filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter column `Temperature`:

```
df['Temperature_TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Temperature_TimeStamp'], dayfirst=True)

mask = df['Temperature_TimeStamp'].between('2020-04-27 05:30:00','2020-04-27 05:32:00')
temp = df.loc[mask, 'Temperature']
print (temp)
0    91.75
1    91.73
2    91.75
3    91.73
4    91.77
Name: Temperature, dtype: float64
```